# Ignore empty comboboxes when saving data to SQL via PHP

Tags: php, filter, combobox, null

I have a form with 4 sets of 4 comboboxes which are visible when different selections are made. I would like the 4 sets of comboboxes to put data into 4 table cells (one for each set) while ignoring the other 3 blank comboboxes. 
The boxes are laid out as below;

```
Lab set 1 - Sample Type 1 - Sample Type 2 - Sample Type 3 - Sample Type 4

Lab set 2 - Sample Type 5 - Sample Type 6 - Sample Type 7 - Sample Type 8

Lab set 3 - Sample Type 9 - Sample Type 10 - Sample Type 11 - Sample Type 12

Lab set 4 - Sample Type 13 - Sample Type 14 - Sample Type 15 - Sample Type 16
```

Only one selection can be made per Lab set at any time, so if Sample Type 1, Sample Type 5, Sample Type 11 and Sample Type 12 are selected the remaining sample types will be NULL.

I would like there to be only one table cell per lab set so that it is easier to display the data later on, is it possible to ignore the null values and populate the Lab set 1, 2, 3, 4 cells with only the selected data or am I trying to do the impossible?

Here is my coding attempt on one of the comboboxes with property disabled as well as visibility hidden;

```
<select name="Lab1" id="Lab1" style="visibility:hidden;" onChange="if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='visible'}if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].prop.disabled='false'}if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].prop.disabled='true'}">
               <option selected>Lab</option>
                <option value="Alpha Bio Labs">Alpha Bio Labs</option>
                <option value="Cellmark">Cellmark</option>
                <option value="DNA Legal">DNA Legal</option>
                <option value="The Doctors Lab">The Doctors Lab</option>
              </select>
```

The onChange coding for visibility is below;

```
//visible
if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='visible'}
//hidden
if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}
```

I have written an extra set of functions that read as follows;

```
//Active    
if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].prop.disabled='false'}
//Not Active
if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].prop.disabled='true'}
```

The above code will run along side the visible code as I want the inactive functions to be invisible and my tests indicate that inactive functions will still be visible.

I have come accross some Javascript online and come up with an attempt to make it fit, I have put the code below;

```
var visopt = document.getElementsById('Samp1');
for(var  strUser = visopt.options [visopt.selectedIndex] .style.visibility;) {
    if(strUser.style.visibility='visible') {
        visopt.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: We would love you see your best coding attempt as part of a complete question.

Comment: I have added the coding that I have so far, I will be removing the login details once I get it working to replace with a more secure way of logging in but sticking with simplicity until I know that it definitely works.

Comment: I had mistakenly left some old code in the coding above, please ignore $lab = $_POST['LabDep']; it isnt in the live version

Comment: Just so you know, you don't have to write the `value` attribute in the `<option>` tags because it is identical to the text value.  You only need to write the attribute if the `value` value (submitted value) is different from what you are displaying to the user.

Comment: I just can't visualize the issue that you are having / the solution that you need.  Your question is too large of a code dump.  Sorry, if you narrow down your question, I'll come back.

Comment: What i want to do is have the coding ignore the hidden comboboxes when saving the data to the table because I want 4 cells (one for each set of comboboxes) with 4 comboboxes linked to each cell (one with data chosen and 3 remain hidden) is that possible?

Comment: So this is a javascript question then?  You want to "turn off" all of the other fields in the same row when one of the select fields is changed.?

Comment: not sure how its done, none of the examples online made it clear which is why I am stuck

Comment: your example sounds like it would do what I am wanting, is it as simple as running some code on each combobox to turn off if null?

Comment: would something along theses lines work?  <select name="Lab1" id="Lab1" style="visibility:hidden;" onChange="if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='visible'}if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].prop.disabled='false'}if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].prop.disabled='true'}">

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to ignore you, but I am busy with other things.  You should definitely add your attempt to your question via edit and while you are editing, you should remove any/all details that are not necessary to get you past this challenge.  This will make your question more attractive to answer.  Also, when you edit your question, it gets bumped to the top of the Active questions list.

Comment: no problem, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have found another question that almost answers my question but using text box however I cant get it to work in my scenario. I used it to base my Javascript on in the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just add a secong link of code to the OnChange function of the Lab selection for each section so that is reads as below;

```
onChange="if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].disabled=false}"
```

This code is repeated and altered for each entry to ensure that it does what is required.

Thank you @mickmackusa for your assistance in the early stages, it got me on the correct track.